# Is there a way to set the character that represents 'n/a' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a CSV file that uses a period '.' sign to represent a null value. For example,

```
item  weight  unit_price
 1      5.1       10
 2      .         20
 3      7.5       30
 4      .         40
 5      2.0       50
```

This is read into a table in MySQL (v. 5.5) using :

```
CREATE TABLE products(
  item SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  weight float DEFAULT NULL,
  unit_price SMALLINT);

LOAD DATA INFILE ".../data.txt"
IGNORE
INTO TABLE products
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The IGNORE keyword in the LOAD DATA block coerces the '.' to a 0 - Is there a way I can set it to NULL instead?

The only fix I've tried is this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ".../data.txt"
IGNORE
INTO TABLE products
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"
IGNORE 1 LINES
(item,
 @weight,
 unit_price
)
SET
 weight = if(@weight = '.', NULL, @weight);
```

However the actual data I'm working with has over 10 million rows and 15 columns where '.' is used to represent nulls. Is there a cleaner way to default to null?

Comment: I would have gone for the same WORKAROUND. After the load the first thing I would do is running an update on all fake null values and turn them into real null values and have a serious conversion with the guy that decided '.' should be the same as null.

Comment: Thanks, I did consider running an UPDATE after importing all the data - but then I would have to import the weight column as a character field (because of the presence of the '.'). That would be undesirable if one wants to use functions like MAX or MIN on the weight column. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't quite get where the character field comes from. If you are allowed to run an update on that column, just update it first and then load the data without any workaround. If you are not allowed to run an update on that column and you need a quick (dirty) solution to that problem, just load it with your query and then try to get permission to run the update.

Comment: is it possible/worth updating the CSV file before loading? something like `sed -i 's/,.,/,\\N,/g' foo.csv` will switch the '.' fields to '\N' which should load as null.

Comment: Thanks @mikeb. That works and its a much cleaner solution that cleaning it in SQL!

Answer (score 0):

use a find and replace tool in the csv to take out the . and replace with ""(nothing) then when you load it it will automaticaly put in NULL for that row under the weight column

Comment: Yep. I'm not sure how other database systems read null values, MySQL needs data files to use a '\N' to represent null values